# Getting Error 'NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.' while calling acmpca.GetCertificate() in golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, golang-migrate

I am facing error while calling acmpca.GetCertificate() function to get certificate,

```
NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain
caused by: EnvAccessKeyNotFound: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID or AWS_ACCESS_KEY not found in environment
SharedCredsLoad: failed to load shared credentials file
caused by: FailedRead: unable to open file
caused by: open /root/.aws/credentials: no such file or directory
EC2RoleRequestError: no EC2 instance role found
caused by: RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Get "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: no route to host
```

My AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY is stored in ~/.aws/credentials file, below is the code

```
sess := acmpca.New(session.New(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-1"),
    }))
    params := &acmpca.GetCertificateInput{
        CertificateArn:          aws.String("ARN"),
        CertificateAuthorityArn: aws.String("ARN"),
    }
    resp, err := sess.GetCertificate(params)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("got error := ", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("++++ response ++++:= %+V", resp)
```

Can anyone please help me on this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: similar issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/2914. did you try this ?

Comment: yes, I already have tried this, but didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The credentials you provided are either expired or they don't have proper permissions set for them. You can try creating new credentials with permissions that are sufficient for code.